# Vim cursor change on specific events

Tags: vim, cursor

I've tried [VsVim](https://github.com/VsVim/VsVim) recently. One nice thing I noticed is when `c` or `d` is entered the cursor shape changes to half-underscore. And after deleting the line with `dd` cursor shape restores to block. Is it possible to add this feature to Vim?

[image: Cursor change on <change>]

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was I think `gvim`, on Windows, which made me get used to a different cursor in normal and insert mode.

You did not specify any terminal; I made a small function in my `.vimrc` for linux console and xterm.

```
" Cursor shape ANSI-Codes
fu Cursor_tve()
if ($TERM == 'linux')
    au! InsertEnter * set t_ve=^[[?3;0;8c^[[?25h
    au! InsertLeave * set t_ve=^[[?192;7;50c^[[?25h
    " yellow
    "set t_ve=^[[?255;16;245c^[[?25h
endif

if ($TERM =~ 'xterm' )
    set t_SI=^[[4\ q
    set t_EI=^[[2\ q
    " for xterm: (just blink)
    "au! InsertEnter * set t_ve=^[[?25h^[[?12h
    "au! InsertLeave * set t_ve=^[[?12l^[[?25h
endif

endfu
```

(To call it I have `call Cursor_tve()` also in .vimrc.)

The `t_SI` for xterm is mentioned in vim's help, try `:h t_SI`. The escape sequence is also a bit hard to find.

For only one terminal type you can leave out the `if ($TERM ==` part

As you see, I first had a yellow cursor. This was neither practical nor did it work well with the shell cursor. Now I have a full cursor for normal mode and a line (xterm) or a quarter block (linux).

Comment: When I press `c` or `d` key (before delete) there's no event <t_SI> yet. It happens after `cw` or `c$` but not earlier. And I want to catch moment when only `c` or `d` key pressed. Maybe there's a special event name for these keys?

Comment: I see...you want more than "c" or "d" bottom right indicating _operator-pending_ mode. So after "dd" you get the normal block cursor restored. And after "cc"? Is there a special cursor indicating insert mode?

Comment: Actually, yes.
And I don't see bottom right indicating *operator-pending* mode. Is it enabled by default?

Comment: operator-pending mode is _not_ affected by 'showmode' option - I don/t even know how to turn it off, in vim 8.1 `:version` 'huge-without-GUI'. _With_ GUI (i.e. gvim?) you have option 'guicursor', where `0:hor50-Cursor` is defined. I actually have it, but it doesn't work in non-GUI vim. This cursor shape thing is quite a portability issue...Did you try `gvim`, or do you insist on `vim`?